# ¿Como pasar el contenido de un textarea, a otro de otra pagina usando JavaScript o Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net

Tengo una página llamada **formulario.aspx**, la cual contiene un formulario con el siguiente código:

```
<textarea name="summernote3" id="summernote" runat="server"></textarea>
<img id="Img2" alt="Editar en pantalla Completa" src="../imagenes/botones/editorpantalla.png" class="clase" onclick="ZoomEdit2('<%=summernote.ClientID %>');" />
```

Ésta es la función que he generado para enviar la información capturada en el `textarea` hacia otra página llamada **editar.aspx**

```
function ZoomEdit2(campo) {
var nw = window.open("../Plugins/editar.aspx?campo=" + campo +"","FORMATO","resizable=1,width=1100,height=600, scrollbars=1");
nw.focus();
}
```

En la segunda página **editar.aspx**, quiero obtener el valor del primer `textarea` y asignarlo a un otro `textarea` y viceversa.

Estuve intentando con algo de ajaxcontrol, pero no logro obtener los resultados deseados:

```
var markupStr = $('#summernote').code();
var txvalor = opener.$get('<%=request("campo")%>').control;
txvalor2.set_content(markupStr);
```

¿Hay alguna manera de intercambiar la información capturada en textareas y enviarlos entre determinadas páginas?

Comment: Lo que quieres es mandar información desde la ventana que abre (formulario) a la que se ha abierto (editar). ¿Es así?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Para pasar información de una página (formulario.aspx) a otra ventana que se abre desde la primera (editar.aspx), tienes varias opciones:

**1) Pasar la información en el GET**

De manera similar a cómo se pasa el nombre del campo, puedes pasar el valor (si no es excesivamente grande) como parte de la URL:

```
function ZoomEdit2(campo) {
    // obtener el valor del campo (podría hacerse de diferentes maneras)
    var valor = document.getElementById(campo).value;
    // abrir la ventana pasando los valores en la URL
    var nw = window.open("../Plugins/editar.aspx?campo=" + campo + "&valor=" + valor,"FORMATO","resizable=1,width=1100,height=600, scrollbars=1");
    nw.focus();
}
```

Ventajas de este método:

- Sencillo
- Implementación similar a la del atributo `campo` que ya procesas

Inconvenientes de este método:

- Hay un límite en el tamaño del valor que puedes pasar
- Los usuarios pueden ver el valor (no ofrece mucha privacidad ni seguridad)

---

**2) Guardar los valores en el LocalStorage**

Otra opción sería guardar el valor en el `LocalStorage` o el `SessionStorage` antes de abrir la ventana y luego leer el valor en la nueva ventana cuando se cargue.

```
function ZoomEdit2(campo) {
    // guardar el valor del campo en el localStorage (podría hacerse de diferentes maneras)
    localStorage.setItem('myCat', document.getElementById(campo).value );
    var nw = window.open("../Plugins/editar.aspx?campo=" + campo + "","FORMATO","resizable=1,width=1100,height=600, scrollbars=1");
    nw.focus();
}
```

Ventajas de este método:

- Sencillo y fácil de implementar
- Puedes guardar más datos de los que podrías pasar a través de la URL

Inconvenientes de este método:

- No funcionará si el usuario tiene deshabilitadas las cookies
- No funcionará si los protocolos no coinciden (http o https, pero no los dos)

---

**3) Leer los datos del padre desde la ventana abierta**

Como se indica en los comentarios y en otra respuesta, podrías acceder a los valores del padre usando `window.parent`, así desde la ventana abierta puedes leer el campo que quieras como esto:

```
var valorEnPadre = window.opener.document.getElementById("ID_DEL_ELEMENTO").value;
```

Suponiendo que el ID del elemento se ha guardado en el atributo `campo` entonces sería:

```
var valorEnPadre = window.opener.document.getElementById(campo).value;
```

Ventajas de este método:

- JavaScript puro y duro sin APIs que puedan fallar ni problemas de compatibilidad con navegadores
- No debería haber problemas de tamaño

Inconvenientes de este método:

- Requiere que las páginas estén en un servidor (funciona con http o https pero no con file://)

Comment: en la segunda opción también podría usar `sessionStorage` en vez de `localStorage` así solo se guardará los valores durante el tiempo de sesión del navegador y se borrarán cuando el navegador se reinicie.

Comment: Excelente respuesta muchas gracias por el dato

Answer (score 2):

Para acceder a los datos de la pagina padre puedes usar el `window.opener`

[Window opener Property](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_opener.asp)

Sobre este es que aplicas el selector de **jQuery** para localizar un control y recuperar su valor, o asignarlo, es tan simple como:

```
window.opener.$("#idcontrol")
```

saludos

Para aclarar un poco el uso de `window.opener`, aquí les dejo un ejemplo de como todo lo que escribimos en una ventana se replicara en la otra (y viceversa).

Ejemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/3vb8643p/2/

```
  <html>
   <head>
    <title>replicar texto en ventanas</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
     w="";
     $("#edit1").on("keypress",function () {
      w.document.getElementById("edit1").value=$(this).val();
     });
     $("button").on("click", function (){
      w = open("", "_blank", "width=200,height=100");
      w.document.write('<textarea id="edit1" onkeypress="window.opener.$(\'#edit1\').val(this.value)"></textarea>');
     });
    <script>
   </head>
   <body>
    <textarea id="edit1"></textarea>
    <button>abrir otra ventana</button>
   </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Gracias por responder a mi pregunta, me quedo duda sobre lo que me comenta al uso "window.opener.$("#idcontrol")" ¿De que forma se implementaría window.opener.$("#idcontrol").value();

Comment: hola, estas usando jquery, usarias el .val() para recuperar o asignar un valor al control seleccionado, window.opener.$("#idcontrol").val();