# ¿Cómo mostrar valores seleccionados de tabla en ventana modal?

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, bootstrap, vb.net

Tengo una tabla donde coloco varios datos resultado de una consulta SQL, para cada registro que regrese una consulta coloco un botón para que muestre los datos en un form del registro que seleccioné hasta el momento sólo puedo recuperar un solo valor con este código, ¿cómo puedo recuperar los demás valores del registro que seleccioné?

```js
$('#modalSi').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
    var id = $(e.relatedTarget).data().id;
    $(e.currentTarget).find('#txtNombre').val(id);
});
```

Éste es el enlace con que abro la ventana modal, a través del atributo `data-id` le paso el valor id que ha seleccionado, se pueden pasar más valores

```html
<a href="#" id="link1" data-id="row.id" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalSi"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Si&nbsp;&nbsp;</button></a>
```

Y éste es el HTML:

```html
<!--modal-->
<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" id="modalSi" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">                            
      <div class="modal-body">
        <!-- body panel -->
        <div id="panelNo" class="panel panel-primary">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Reporte de renovación </h3>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            <form class="form-horizontal">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="lblNombre" class="control-label col-sm-2">Nombre</label>
                <div class="input-group date col-sm-10">
                  <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
                  </span>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtNombre" disabled>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="lblTelefono" class="control-label col-sm-2">Telefono</label>
                <div class="input-group date col-sm-10">
                  <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone"></span>
                  </span>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtTelefono" disabled>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="lblFechaa" class="control-label col-sm-2">Fecha Activación</label>
                <div class="input-group date col-sm-10">
                  <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                  </span>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtFechaa" disabled>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="lbltipoTramite" class="control-label col-sm-2">Opciones</label>
                <div class="input-group date col-sm-10">
                  <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></span>
                  </span>
                  <select name="tipo" size="1" id="tipo" class="form-control">
                    <option value="">--Seleccionar--</option>
                    <option value="1">Buzón</option>
                    <option value="2">Fuera de servicio / número ha cambiado</option>
                    <option value="3">No contesta</option>
                  </select>
                </div>

              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-2"></label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <input type="button" name="Submit" value="Guardar" id="btn-enviar" class="btn btn-success" />
                </div>

              </div>

            </form>
          </div>                                   
        </div>                            
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--modal-->
```

Comment: que tecnologia usas del lado del servidor ?

Comment: Teniendo en cuenta que lo que se busca es pasar valores desde una documento/ventana a otra, esto es un posible duplicado de [¿Como pasar el contenido de un textarea, a otro de otra pagina usando JavaScript o Jquery?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/2261/como-pasar-el-contenido-de-un-textarea-a-otro-de-otra-pagina-usando-javascript)

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro como puede ser un duplicado si en este caso se trata de una tabla desde donde se toma el datos, no es un textbox Y ademas es un popup de bootstrap, no es otra pagina, el popup esta en la misma pagina

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considerando que el link está dentro de una etiqueta **td** y esta dentro de una etiqueta **tr** que contiene el resto de celdas con sus valores: Te doy un ejemplo detallado de como obtendría todos los valores de una fila

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Columna 1 1</td> 
    <td>Columna 1 2</td>  
    <td><a href="#"><button>Get Fila</button></a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Columna 2 1</td>
    <td>Columna 2 2</td>
    <td><a href="#"><button>Get Fila</button></a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

En tu aplicación como estás utilizando JQuery, en el evento **show.bs.modal** que usás, podrías aplicar la función **parent()** dos veces.

```
var row= $(e.relatedTarget).parent().parent()
```

Eso te devolvería la fila en la que se encuentra el link que presionó el usuario. Con JQuery podés obtener todos los elementos que contiene esa fila, es decir, todas sus celdas(nivel 1) y el contenido de estas(nivel 2).

Para obtener todos los elementos hijos(en este ejemplo celdas) de la fila se puede utilizar la función **children()** de JQuery. Esta devolverá, en este caso, un array de elementos **td**

El recorrido de los elementos podés hacerlo con un **each**

```
row.children().each(function () {
  var celda= this;
  //Con $(celda).text() obtendrías el contenido de la celda que es lo que buscás
```

});

El problema de esto es que en tu problema necesitás relacionar cada celda con un elemento del formulario. Seguramente hay alternativas mas elegantes pero voy a optar por la versión simple: recorrés cada posición del array manualmente

```
var celdas= row.children();
//$(celdas[0]).text() te daría el contenido de la primer celda de la fila 
//$(celdas[1]).text() te daría el contenido de la segunda celda de la fila
//etc
```

Armé un pequeño ejemplo, no incluye bootstrap ni el modal ni el formulario. Pero sirve para ver como obtener la fila y recorrer sus celdas. Espero te sirva.

[Link para ver el ejemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/ibooio/qxn5bv0e/)

Algo importante a mencionar es que he visto otras respuestas y te aconsejaría que las consideres. Yo me limité a resolverlo en base a lo que tenías, sin alejarme demasiado de lo que estabas haciendo, sin acceder al lado del servidor(.net) y sin recurrir a otras librerías. Esto funcionaría y te resolvería tu problema rápidamente, pero te aconsejo que consideres a futuro otras formas de solucionar situaciones como estas.

Yo optaría por tomar el id y con él traer los datos desde el servidor.

Suerte!

Comment: si es lo que requiero pero entoces la funcion children como la usaria para recuperar mis otros valores de la fila

Comment: La función te va a retornar un array que en cada posición contiene una de las celdas de la fila. Al recorrer el array, a cada objeto(celda) le pedís su contenido.

Comment: seria algo asi?                 var hola = $(e.relatedTarget.hash).parent().parent();
                for (var x in hola){
                    alert(hola[x].children());
                }

Comment: Ahora edito la respuesta con un ejemplo mas claro

Comment: si por favor, te agradezco

Comment: excelente me funciono perfecto @ibooio saludos

Answer (score 1):

La opción que propone [Leandro Tutini](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/2600/leandro-tuttini) me parece más adecuada que la de ir recorriendo con jQuery los elementos HTML de la fila que estás editando.

Como complemento a su respuesta:

Para rellenar los datos del formulario podrías usar un plugin de jQuery como [jQuery-form-autofill](https://github.com/creative-area/jQuery-form-autofill) que te facilitara el trabajo y llegar a tener algo como esto:

```
var params = new {
    id: $(e.relatedTarget).data().id
};

$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "Pagina1.aspx/GetDatosReporte",
   data: params,
   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   dataType: "json"
}).done(function( data ) {
    // Rellenar los campos del formulario
    $("#formId").autofill(data);
});
```

Para guardar los cambios realizados en el formulario necesitarías otro WebMethod

```
<System.Web.Services.WebMethod()> _
Public Shared Function GuardaDatosReporte(ByVal data As ClassCustom)
    'aqui te conectas a la db filtrando por el id
    ' guardas los datos de la entidad
End Function
```

Y en el botón de guardar podrías usar [jQuery.serializeArray()](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) para obtener los datos del formulario y enviarlos a servidor. El código sería parecido a este:

```
var params = $('#formId').serializeArray();

$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "Pagina1.aspx/GuardaDatosReporte",
   data: params,
   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   dataType: "json"
}).done(function( data ) {
    //TODO: Cerrar el formulario
})
.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
    //TODO: Mostrar error
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Con solo el `id` que consigues de la tabla alcanza y sobra para poder cargar el popup. Deberias utilizar con `jquery` y una llamada `ajax` al servidor para recuperar los datos y cargar los controles de la ventana.
O sea no tomas los datos desde el html, sino que debes ir al servidor a buscarlos.

[Calling ASP.Net WebMethod using jQuery AJAX](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Calling-ASPNet-WebMethod-using-jQuery-AJAX.aspx)

Se define un `webmethod` del lado del servidor

```
<System.Web.Services.WebMethod()> _
Public Shared Function GetDatosReporte(ByVal id As Integer) As ClassCustom
    'aqui te conectas a la db filtrando por el id
    ' devuelves la lista con los datos de la entidad
End Function
```

Por supuesto debes definir la clase con las propiedades de la entidad que edita el popup

Usaras `jquery` con `$.ajax` para invocar el webmethod

```
 var params = new {
        id: $(e.relatedTarget).data().id
  };

 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Pagina1.aspx/GetDatosReporte",
    data: params,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: OnSuccess,
    failure: function(response) {
        alert(response.d);
    }
});
```

la respuesta la usarias para asignar los controles usando jquery