# ventana modal desde tabla

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, bootstrap, datatables

Tengo una tabla como se muestra en la imagen,[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] y deseo mostrar una ventana modal al dar clic en el icono de ver de cada registro, en la ventana modal se debe buscar y mostrar los detalles del registro seleccionado como se muestra en la imagen (es donde pretendo llegar),[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] para esto tengo lo siguiente:

Esquema de la tabla.

tentativamente ubique aqui la ventana modal con el fin que sea una sola para todas las filas pero no estoy seguro donde se debe ubicar el `div` modal

```
<div class="modal fade custom-modal" id="modalInvoiceView"  tabindex="-1" role="document" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
    <?php
        include_once("adm_invoice_view.php");
    ?>
</div>

<div class="pcoded-inner-content">
    <div class="main-body">
        <div class="page-wrapper">
            <!-- Page body start -->
            <div class="page-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12">                     
                        <div class="card mb-3">
                            <div class="card-block">
                                <table id="tblInvoice" class="table dt-responsive table-striped table-bordered nowrap js-table" style="width:100%">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th width="80" valign="middle">Numero</th>
                                            <th width="150" valign="middle">Fecha</th>
                                            <th width="150" valign="middle">Vence</th>
                                            <th width="500" valign="middle">Cliente</th>
                                            <th width="200" valign="middle">Almacen</th>
                                            <th width="150" valign="middle">Total</th>
                                            <th width="150" valign="middle">Saldo</th>
                                            <th width="100" valign="middle">Estado</th>
                                            <th width="150" valign="middle">Acciones</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tfoot>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th width="80" valign="middle">Numero</th>
                                            <th width="150" valign="middle">Fecha</th>
                                            <th width="150" valign="middle">Vence</th>
                                            <th width="500" valign="middle">Cliente</th>
                                            <th width="200" valign="middle">Almacen</th>
                                            <th width="150" valign="middle">Total</th>
                                            <th width="150" valign="middle">Saldo</th>
                                            <th width="100" valign="middle">Estado</th>
                                            <th width="150" valign="middle">Acciones</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tfoot>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <!-- dataatables -->
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>  
                            <!-- end card-body -->                              
                        </div>
                        <!-- end card -->                   
                    </div>
                    <!-- end col -->    
                </div>
            <!-- end row -->    
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

El llenado de la tabla, esto lo hago por medio de ajax desde un archivo que contiene el `SELECT`  a la tabla MySql, la linea que se inserta en cada registro y que llama la ventana modal es

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalInvoiceView" data-invid="'. $row['inv_id'].'" title="Ver"><i class="icofont icofont-eye"></i></a>
```

Archivo que muestra la ventana

Lo primero que se debe hacer es buscar el registro, aqui tengo el primer problema como llevo hasta aqui el id de la factura?, notese que he utilizado el atributo `data-invid` para enviar el id de la facura, como lo recupero aqui?, hay otro metodo para enviar el id?

```
<?php
if (!empty($_REQUEST['invid'])){
    exit;
}

$regId = 939; //he puesto este numero aqui para que funcione el ejemplo

//selecciona el registro de factura
$sql = "SELECT * FROM invoice_master WHERE inv_id='$regId'";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

// muestra los datos organizados y un boton de cerrar la ventana modal...
```

Para el ejemplo he igualado el `regId` a 939 que es el id de una factura cualquiera de manera que todas filas van a mostar el mismo, solo lo hice para porder mostar el resultado requerido, si lo quito, la tabla no se muestra y esto me hace pensar que no tengo bien ubicado el div de la ventana modal...

Gracias por su valiosa ayuda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando incluyes `include_once("adm_invoice_view.php");` no puedes dar solución a tu inquietud. Es necesario que tengas la estructura del modal en la vista, pero que uses una estructura Ajax para que sea más fácil.

Mira la [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18995461/how-can-i-show-data-using-a-modal-when-clicking-a-table-row-using-bootstrap) a una pregunta muy similar que te puede ayudar.

También tienes esta otra [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/4477/c%C3%B3mo-mostrar-valores-seleccionados-de-tabla-en-ventana-modal?rq=1).

Comment: Los enlaces que estás citando podrían _romperse_ y no servir en un futuro, por favor considera editar tu respuesta agregando la información relevante de dichos enlaces